# How to do an unfold / unwrap animation for Cone shape in Three.js?

Tags: animation, three.js

I try to do a cone unwrap animation for students to better understand.

It should look like this (found on http://www.onlinemathlearning.com/geometry-nets-animations.html):

[this is the fold/unfold cone image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiOQK.png)

I tried this but this is not similar to image please help me I tried alot

```
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
  var sides = [];
  var clock = new THREE.Clock();

  var isDragging = false;
  var previousMousePosition = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
  };
  var nSides = 3;
  var side0, side5, hPlane, vPlane;
  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(-0.1, 0.1, 1).setLength(3);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(800, 500);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0,0);
    side0 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'yellow',
                      transparent:true, 
                      opacity:0,
                      // side: THREE.DoubleSide 
                    }));
    scene.add(side0);
    side0.scale.set( 0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
    resultData(5,5);

    var side1Geom = PolygonGeometry(6);
    side1 = new THREE.Mesh(side1Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'blue', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));

    sides.push(side1); 
    side1.scale.set( 0.2588, 0.2588, 0.2588 ); 

    var side2Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side2Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side2 = new THREE.Mesh(side2Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:0xff0000, 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side2);  
    side2.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  


    var side3Geom = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 1, 30 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                        color:'blue',
                        transparent:true,
                        opacity:0.8,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                      });
    side3 = new THREE.Mesh( side3Geom, material );
    sides.push(side3); 

    var side4Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side4Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side4 = new THREE.Mesh(side4Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'#FFA500', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side4);  
    side4.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side5Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side5Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side5 = new THREE.Mesh(side5Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:0xff00ff, 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side5);  
    side5.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side6Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side6Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side6 = new THREE.Mesh(side6Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'green', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side6);  
    side6.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side7Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side7Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side7 = new THREE.Mesh(side7Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'yellow', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side7);  
    side7.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side8Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side8Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side8 = new THREE.Mesh(side8Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'brown', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side8);  
    side8.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side9Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side9Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side9 = new THREE.Mesh(side9Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'blue', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side9);  
    side9.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side10Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side10Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side10 = new THREE.Mesh(side10Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'red', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side10);  
    side10.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side11Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side11Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side11 = new THREE.Mesh(side11Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'green', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side11);  
    side11.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side12Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side12Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side12 = new THREE.Mesh(side12Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'pink', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side12);  
    side12.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side13Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side13Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side13 = new THREE.Mesh(side13Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'yellow', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side13);  
    side13.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side14Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side14Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side14 = new THREE.Mesh(side14Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'yellow', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side14);  
    side14.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side15Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side15Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side15 = new THREE.Mesh(side15Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'pink', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side15);  
    side15.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side16Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side16Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side16 = new THREE.Mesh(side16Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'green', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side16);  
    side16.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side17Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side17Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side17 = new THREE.Mesh(side17Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'green', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side17);  
    side17.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  


    var side18Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side18Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side18 = new THREE.Mesh(side18Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'yellow', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side18);  
    side18.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side19Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side19Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side19 = new THREE.Mesh(side19Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'red', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side19);  
    side19.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side20Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side20Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side20 = new THREE.Mesh(side20Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'brown', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side20);  
    side20.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side21Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side21Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side21 = new THREE.Mesh(side21Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'blue', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side21);  
    side21.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side22Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side22Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side22 = new THREE.Mesh(side22Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'pink', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side22);  
    side22.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side23Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side23Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side23 = new THREE.Mesh(side23Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'red', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side23);  
    side23.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side24Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side24Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side24 = new THREE.Mesh(side24Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'yellow', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side24);  
    side24.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side25Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side25Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side25 = new THREE.Mesh(side25Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'green', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side25);  
    side25.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side26Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side26Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side26 = new THREE.Mesh(side26Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'brown', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side26);  
    side26.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side27Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side27Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side27 = new THREE.Mesh(side27Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'pink', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side27);  
    side27.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side28Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side28Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side28 = new THREE.Mesh(side28Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'red', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side28);  
    side28.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side29Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side29Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side29 = new THREE.Mesh(side29Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'yellow', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side29);  
    side29.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side30Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side30Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side30 = new THREE.Mesh(side30Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'green', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side30);  
    side30.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side31Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side31Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side31 = new THREE.Mesh(side31Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'blue', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side31);  
    side31.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    var side32Geom = PolygonGeometry(3);
    side32Geom.translate(0,0.5,0);
    var side32 = new THREE.Mesh(side32Geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                      color:'yellow', 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.8, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
    sides.push(side32);  
    side32.scale.set(0.12, 0.84, 0.12);  

    // hierarchy
    side2.position.set(0.5,0.1,0.98); 
    side2.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side2.rotation.x = -0.1;
    side2.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side2);

    side3.position.set(0.5,0,0); 
    side3.rotation.z = Math.PI;
    side3.rotation.y = -1.57;
    side3.rotation.x = 0;
    side0.add(side3);

    side4.position.set(0.5,-0.1,0.98); 
    side4.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side4.rotation.x = 0.09;
    side4.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side4);

    side5.position.set(0.5,0.1,-0.98); 
    side5.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side5.rotation.x = 0.15;
    side5.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side5);

    side6.position.set(0.5,-0.1,-0.99); 
    side6.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side6.rotation.x = -0.05;
    side6.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side6);

    side7.position.set(0.5,0.3,-0.95);
    side7.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side7.rotation.x = 0.33;
    side7.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side7);

    side8.position.set(0.5,-0.3,-0.95); 
    side8.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side8.rotation.x = -0.24;
    side8.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side8);

    side9.position.set(0.5,-0.5,-0.87); 
    side9.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side9.rotation.x = -0.48;
    side9.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side9);

    side10.position.set(0.5,0.5,-0.87); 
    side10.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side10.rotation.x = 0.55;
    side10.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side10);

    side11.position.set(0.5,0.67,-0.75);
    side11.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side11.rotation.x = 0.74;
    side11.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side11);

    side14.position.set(0.5,-0.66,-0.75); 
    side14.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side14.rotation.x = -0.7;
    side14.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side14);

    side12.position.set(0.5,0.8,-0.57); 
    side12.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side12.rotation.x = 0.98;
    side12.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side12);

    side15.position.set(0.5,-0.8,-0.6); 
    side15.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side15.rotation.x = -0.92;
    side15.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side15);

    side13.position.set(0.5,0.9,-0.4); 
    side13.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side13.rotation.x = 1.2;
    side13.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side13);

    side16.position.set(0.5,-0.91,-0.42); 
    side16.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side16.rotation.x = -1.15;
    side16.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side16);

    side17.position.set(0.5,0.91,0.42); 
    side17.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side17.rotation.x = -1.15;
    side17.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side17);

    side18.position.set(0.5,-0.9,0.4); 
    side18.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side18.rotation.x = 1.2;
    side18.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side18);

    side19.position.set(0.5,-0.67,0.75); 
    side19.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side19.rotation.x = 0.74;
    side19.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side19);

    side20.position.set(0.5,0.66,0.75); 
    side20.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side20.rotation.x = -0.7;
    side20.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side20);

    side21.position.set(0.5,-0.8,0.57); 
    side21.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side21.rotation.x = 0.98;
    side21.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side21);

    side22.position.set(0.5,0.8,0.6); 
    side22.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side22.rotation.x = -0.92;
    side22.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side22);

    side23.position.set(0.5,-0.3,0.95); 
    side23.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side23.rotation.x = 0.33;
    side23.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side23);

    side24.position.set(0.5,0.3,0.95); 
    side24.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side24.rotation.x = -0.28;
    side24.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side24);

    side25.position.set(0.5,0.5,0.87); 
    side25.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side25.rotation.x = -0.48;
    side25.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side25);

    side26.position.set(0.5,-0.5,0.87); 
    side26.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side26.rotation.x = 0.55;
    side26.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side26);

    side27.position.set(0.5,-0.97,0.2); 
    side27.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side27.rotation.x = 1.4;
    side27.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side27);

    side28.position.set(0.5,0.97,-0.2); 
    side28.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side28.rotation.x = 1.4;
    side28.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side28);

    side29.position.set(0.5,0.99,0); 
    side29.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side29.rotation.x = 1.6;
    side29.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side29);

    side30.position.set(0.5,-0.99,0); 
    side30.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side30.rotation.x = 1.6;
    side30.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side30);

    side31.position.set(0.5,-0.98,-0.22); 
    side31.rotation.y = -0.95; //-0.95
    side31.rotation.x = 1.8;
    side31.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side31);

    side32.position.set(0.5,0.98,0.22); 
    side32.rotation.y = 0.95; //-0.95
    side32.rotation.x = 1.8;
    side32.rotation.z = Math.PI/2;
    side0.add(side32);

    $(renderer.domElement).on('mousedown', function(e) {
        isDragging = true;
    }).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        var deltaMove = {
            x: e.offsetX-previousMousePosition.x,
            y: e.offsetY-previousMousePosition.y
        };

        if(isDragging) {
            var deltaRotationQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
                .setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(
                    toRadians(deltaMove.y * 1),
                    toRadians(deltaMove.x * 1),
                    0,
                    'XYZ'
                ));

            side0.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, side0.quaternion);
        }

        previousMousePosition = {
            x: e.offsetX,
            y: e.offsetY
        };
    });

    // foldTheCube(0);
  }

  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        isDragging = false;
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#slider").slider({
          max: 0.95,
          min: -1.57,
          step: 0.01,
          value: 0.95,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            foldTheCube(ui.value); 
          }
      });
  });

  function foldTheCube(ang){
    var start = {value: 0};
    var finish = {value: Math.PI / 2};
    var angle = 0;
    new TWEEN
      .Tween(start)
      .to(finish, 3000)
      .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut)
      .onUpdate(function(){
        angle = ang;

        sides[1].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[3].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[4].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[5].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[6].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[7].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[8].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[9].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[10].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[11].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[12].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[13].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[14].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[15].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[16].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[17].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[18].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[19].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[20].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[21].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[22].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[23].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[24].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[25].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[26].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[27].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[28].rotation.y = angle;
        sides[29].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[30].rotation.y = -angle;
        sides[31].rotation.y = angle;
      })
      .start();
  }

  function PolygonGeometry(sides) 
  {
    var geo = new THREE.Geometry();
    // generate vertices
    for ( var pt = 0 ; pt < sides; pt++ ){
      var angle = (Math.PI/2) + (pt / sides) * 2 * Math.PI;
      var x = Math.cos( angle );
      var y = Math.sin( angle );
      geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x,y,0));
    }  
    for ( var i = 0; i< sides-2; i++) {
      geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,i+1,i+2));      
    }
    return geo;
  }   

  function drawTriangle (vertex1, vertex2, vertex3) 
  {
      var triangleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
      var triangleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                                    color:0x0000ff, 
                                    transparent:true, 
                                    opacity:0.8, 
                                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                                 });
      var triangle = new THREE.Mesh(triangleGeometry, triangleMaterial);

      triangleGeometry.vertices = [vertex1, vertex2, vertex3];
      triangleGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));

      THREE.GeometryUtils.center(triangleGeometry);
      return triangle;
  }

  function changeCubeRatio(obj){
    var height = Number($('#height-ratio').val());
    var width = Number($('#width-ratio').val());
    resultData(width,height);
    width = width/10;
    height = height/10;
    side0.scale.set( height, width, width );
  }

  function addVertPlane(obj){
    if($(obj).is(':checked')){
      var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2,2);
      vPlane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                        // color:0x00ff00, 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.4, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                      }));

      // vPlane.position.set(0,0,0.5);
      side0.add(vPlane);
    }else{
      side0.remove(vPlane);  
    }  
  }

  function addHoriPlane(obj){
    if($(obj).is(':checked')){
      var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2,2);
      hPlane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                        // color:0x00ff00, 
                        transparent:true, 
                        opacity:0.4, 
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                      }));

      // hPlane.position.set(0,0,0.5);
      hPlane.rotation.x = 1.58;
      side0.add(hPlane);
    }else{
      side0.remove(hPlane);  
    }  
  }

  // animate
  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    TWEEN.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }

  function toRadians(angle) {
    return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
  }
  function toDegrees(angle) {
    return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
  }
  function resultData(baseEdgeCalc,HeightCalc){
    var baseArea = (Math.pow(baseEdgeCalc,2)*nSides) / (4 * Math.tan(Math.PI/nSides));
    var lateralArea = nSides * baseEdgeCalc * HeightCalc;
    var surfaceArea = (2 * baseArea) + lateralArea;
    var volume = baseArea * HeightCalc;

    console.log('baseArea::',baseArea);
    console.log('lateralArea::',lateralArea);
    console.log('surfaceArea::',surfaceArea);
    console.log('volume::',volume);
  }
```

I am new with three.js, so I would also need a suggestion here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would approach the issue differently: model the unfolding cone in blender, add animation and then put animation to three.js.

Could you please make a jsfiddle or similar online example? This is a lot of code to analyze.

Comment: I agree, probably with [keyframes](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_keyframes_json.html)